# OSError('sndfile library not found') in librosa while deploying in azure app service

Tags: python

**Summarize.yml**

```
name: Build and deploy Python app to Azure Web App - summarize1

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up Python version
      uses: actions/setup-python@v1
      with:
        python-version: '3.6'

    - name: Create and start virtual environment
      run: |
        python -m venv venv
        source venv/bin/activate
        
                                        
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        pip install -r requirements.txt
        sudo apt-get update
        sudo apt install autoconf autogen automake build-essential libasound2-dev \
        libflac-dev libogg-dev libtool libvorbis-dev libopus-dev libmp3lame-dev \
        libmpg123-dev pkg-config python
        sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

**requirements.txt**

```
numba==0.48.0
git+https://github.com/librosa/librosa
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: unable to deploy python flask app in azure app service due to the error librosa library.

Answer (score -1):

Consider writing a script (i.e. apt-get install -y libsndfile1) that will install the dependencies manually (via apt-get when the App Service starts up. Configure the App Service in Azure to call that script (i.e. startup.sh) when it starts up. Check out: https://pypi.org/project/SoundFile/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).